# Change table name for django model in runtime

Tags: python, django, django-models

**Example**

Django model with table name:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = "default_table_name"
```

than i have a few filters(in the real world more than 1):

```
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(id=42)
```

**Question**

How can i change model name ("default_table_name") dynamically, in runtime, request can have 'table_name' in 'query_params'?

**It doesn't work:**

1 I can't change "db_table" directly:

```
qs.model._meta.db_table = request.query_params.get('table_name’)
```

2 Raw query is too complicated. I don't want to convert all filters to SQL by myself.

```
MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id=42', [request.query_params.get('table_name’)])
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) wouldn't directly answer your question but offers a possible solution to your problem, assuming you don't have an arbitrary/indeterminate number of db tables.

Answer (score 3):

Please look at: `path/to/venv/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py`

```py
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    ...
    @cached_property
    def cached_col(self):
        from django.db.models.expressions import Col 
        return Col(self.model._meta.db_table, self)
```

There are `@cached_property cached_col`, thus the code `model._meta.db_table = something` will work only if your request is the first request to the model in the python process.

You have to change cachel_cols' too.

```py
from typing import Type, ContextManager, Text
from contextlib import contextmanager
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import Field


@contextmanager
def patch_db_table(model, db_table):  # type: (Type[models.Model], Text) -> ContextManager[Type[models.Model]]
    """
    The context manager to change a table name of a django model

    :param model: A class of django model to be patched
    :param db_table: a new table name
    """
    model_meta = model._meta  # noqa
    old_db_table = model_meta.db_table  # save old table name
    model_meta.db_table = db_table  # set new table name
    for field in model_meta.fields:  # type: Field
        field.cached_col.alias = db_table  # patch all field of a model
    yield model
    model_meta.db_table = old_db_table
    for field in model_meta.fields:  # type: Field
        field.cached_col.alias = old_db_table


# USING
with patch_db_table(your_model_cls, 'new_table_name'):
    your_model_cls.objects.all()  # make your query here
```